# Replicating Codeigniters load function

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, instance-variables

I have recently been playing around with Codeigniter to see what I can learn from it. I came across the load function and was wondering if anyone knows how its done. Basically, it looks something like:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');
$this->Model_name->some_function();
```

Now load is obviously a class and an instance is created and called load. And load includes the class "Model_name" and creates an instance of it. But the part I cant work out, is how does the load class create a "class variable" named "Model_name" to be used as in the second line of the code? And how would I actually go about implementing this in php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the class basicly does is remembering all the created objects ($this for instance) and then assign the newly created class by reference as a variable in those classes.

```
function Load($className)
{
  $newClass = new $className();
  foreach($this->objects as &$object) //objects is array with created objects
    $object->$className = $newClass;
}
```

however, it does a lot more stuff in the background than that. You know you can just open 'loader.php' and then read what it does, right?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things work with interpreted languages like PHP. Though it can be very confusing to picture this, specially if you are experienced with strict languages such as C++, C# etc.

The idea is, there are PHP functions that can execute PHP code and the result will be visible elsewhere in the script.